# Form with custom url keeps submitting to Create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes, rails-routing

I'm trying to build a simple form that passes a few params to a controller.

Here's what I have:

```
<%= form_tag({url: order_pizza_path}, method: :post) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :id, value: 0, name:"tag-1" %>
  <!-- hidden field is then filled in with js -->
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<!-- routes: -->
get 'pizza/new' => 'pizza#new', as: 'new_pizza'
post 'pizza' => 'pizza#create', as: 'create_pizza'
post 'order_pizza' => 'pizza#order', as: 'order_pizza'
```

But when I submit, it keeps trying to point to the `Create` method in my Pizza controller. I keep getting the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in PizzaController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: pizza
```

The form's url is `/pizza`. This is the url of the error: `/pizza?method=get&url=%2Forder_pizza`

---

This happens even if I change it to a GET request not POST. Why does my browser keep trying to go to the `Create` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
form_tag(order_pizza_path, method: :post)
```

not

```
form_tag({url: order_pizza_path}, method: :post)
```

`{url: order_pizza_path}` is not a valid `url_for_options` so the `form_tag` will submit to the default, which is the `create` action.

A valid value for `url_for_options` would be

```
{action: 'order'}
```

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I used my syntax successfully before. Thanks! Do you know why the browser is defaulting to Create rather than just throwing an error?